# Can I connect AWS Neptune to Tableau Desktop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-neptune

Just a simple question, can I connect AWS Neptune to Tableau Desktop?

If yes, then how?

And also, can I write query in SPARQL using new Custom SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the supported connections mentioned [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/exampleconnections_overview.htm), there is no direct connection.

What you can try is using the backup present in S3 and connect it to Tableau desktop utilising the `Amazon Athena` connection option as mentioned [here](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/5/connect-your-s3-data-amazon-athena-connector-tableau-103-71105).